# Parallel execution for programs for each file in dir in bash

Tags: bash

How can I divide work on all  files in a directory  to several cpus using bash without using the parallel command

Answer (score 3):

```
NR_CPUS=3
format=.jpg
job_count=0
for f in *."$format"; do
    mycommand "$f" &
    job_count=$((job_count+1))
    if [ "$job_count" -eq $NR_CPUS ]; then
        wait
        job_count=0
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what I need

Answer (score 2):

The `xargs` command together with the `find` command is often used in this situation; like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 4 echo
```

You'll need to replace the `4` with the maximum number of simultaneous processes you want (typically the same as the number of physical cores in your computer for CPU-bound tasks) and `echo` with the actual name of the program you want to run on those files.

The option `maxdepth` prevents `find` from recursing in the directory (remove it if you want recursion), and the pair `-print0`/`-0` is there to handle word splitting safely in the output of `find` (typically to guard against filenames with spaces in them)

Answer (score 1):

You can spawn a seperate process for each file (that's what parallel does... much more cleverly)

```
 for f in *.jpg; do
   some_program_or_shell_function $f &
 done
```

Comment: what if  you have 1000 files  and only 2 cpus ?

Comment: 1000 processes is no problem at all. It depends on what the process does. Does it need a lot of CPU? then one should limit it to the number of cores. If it is IO limited, then you don't need to limit the number of processes (you should simply test if you benefit from parallelization).

Comment: Even in the case of a CPU-limited job, the decision to limit the number of processes depends on whether you care about *some* jobs finishing as soon as possible, or just the complete *set* finishing as soon as possible. In the latter case, it's easier to spawn them all and let the OS worry about scheduling them on the available cores.

Comment: well my goal was to  convert n video files  and  that costs a lot of memory I believe that usually it is better to start less processes so they dont eat each others resources (memory bandwith...)